# Fix the NumShards while writing Streaming data to GCS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam-io

Actually I'm trying to dump stream data to BigTable in case something fails because of parsing or any other issue, I'm dumping that record to GCS. So I'm applying fixed window here, but one thing that concerns me is the num shards. How to specify the num shards and how exactly the num shards work while writing data to GCS.

```
.apply(Window.<String>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(30L))))
               .apply(TextIO.write().to("gs:").withWindowedWrites());
```

In case the num shards limit exceed, is it like TextIO will overwrite the existing file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of shards setting cannot end up overwritting files. It is the number of files to be written, in this case, to storage (per-window). By modifying this value you can range from trying to write all the window into a single file, to writing each element into a single file.

The number of shards determine how many parallel writes to storage will be done. For this reason, this setting is really important when considering the performance of the pipeline. A higher number of shards, will be more easily parallelized, but it will produce a lot of files. A smaller number of shards, will create less files, but will restrict the parallelism.

According to the beam [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.Write.html#withNumShards-int-):

> Setting this value is not recommended unless you require a specific number of output files.

If you don't set this value, it will be decided by the runner used. For example, [DataflowRunner](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/DataflowRunner.java#L1882) uses the maximum number of workers setting in your pipeline to set the number of shards.

Comment: In case I'm setting numShards to 60 and running the streaming job for 100 days, so you are saying it will just create 60 files and append the data in 60 files for 100 days. I hope my assumption is correct.

Comment: TextIO will write a new file, so if the file already exists, it will be overwritten. [By default](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.19.0/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/DefaultFilenamePolicy.java#L71) the windowed files contain in the name the window, pane and shard information so if you have 30 seconds windows, each one with 60 shards, each minute you'll have around 120 files. In 100 days, you'll have (120 files per minutes) * (1440 minutes per day) * 100 days. Also, as far as I know, there's no out-of-the-box configuration to append instead of overwrite with TextIO